# R compare data frames by differences in occurrences of elements in character variable

Tags: r, compare, dataframe

1Given two data frames how can one find the rows in which the number of occurrences of elements in a variable/column are different between the data frames. For instance, given the two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    id=c(1,2,3,4),
    score=c("AA","BB","BB","BA"))


df2 <- data.frame(
    id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
    score=c("AA","BB","BB","BB","BA","BC"))
```

The number of occurences of each string in score can be found and added row-wise to df1 by e.g.

```
library('dplyr')
df1 <- join(df1, ddply(df1, .(score), 'nrow'))
```

But how can I get a subset of df1 that contains only rows where scores with a different occurrence in df2 ? I would expect a result consisting of rows 2 and 3 (id 2 and 3) since "BB" occurs 2 times in df1 and 3 in df2, while "AA" and "BA" both occur 1 time in each df. Obviously, another result is expected if we asked for df2 in df1

Comment: I updated the code for `df2`.  You can also use `setdiff` for `df1` if there are some scores in `df1` that doesn't exist in `df2`.  In the example, it was not the case.

Comment: Could you show your expected output also? I am a bit confused by the description.

Comment: @akrun Your output is what I want in this small example. I have larger data frames (1000s rows) and these dfs probably have values lacking both ways - but the `setdiff` code should be general I guess

Comment: You can use `setdiff` in that case. So, the more general one would be the second code (for df2) that I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we can check the `frequency` of `score` for each datasets using `table`.  Then, look for the `names` in that `tables` that are common to both datasets using `intersect`.  Once that is done, we want to find which of the frequencies in that common names differ with respect to each other as well as the names of the `table` in the intended dataset that is not in the common names.  Concatenate both using `c` and then check `scores` in the dataset that have these values to subset the dataset.

```
tb1 <- table(df1[,2])
tb2 <- table(df2[,2])
int <- intersect(names(tb1), names(tb2))
df1[df1$score %in%int[tb1[int]!=tb2[int]],]
#  id score
#2  2    BB
#3  3    BB

df2[df2$score %in% c(setdiff(names(tb2), int), int[tb1[int]!=tb2[int]]),]
#    id score
#2  2    BB
#3  3    BB
#4  4    BB
#6  6    BC
```

#### EDIT

You can wrap this in a function

```
 f1 <- function(dat1, dat2){
    tbl1 <- table(dat1$score)
    tbl2 <- table(dat2$score)
    inT <- intersect(names(tbl1), names(tbl2))
    dat1[dat1$score %in% c(setdiff(names(tbl1), inT),
                         inT[tbl1[inT]!=tbl2[inT]]),]

   }

 f1(df1, df2)
 #  id score
 #2  2    BB
 #3  3    BB

 f1(df2,df1)
 #  id score
 #2  2    BB
 #3  3    BB
 #4  4    BB
 #6  6    BC
```

Comment: I was unclear it appears: "BC" should also come up when you do it in the reverse (its 1 time in df2 but 0 in df1). Tough code - I thought there would be a easier way around.

Comment: @user3375672 But `BC` is not in `df2`.  I thought you wanted to subset by looking into those matching elements in `score` that differ in frequency.

Comment: No, intended those elements in `score` in one df that occurs with different rates (incl 0 times) in another df. Not only on the matching values of `score`. (and "BC" is in df2 not df1).

Comment: Trying to workout what the code precisely does so I can wrap it in a function

Comment: @user3375672 I will add some explanation

Comment: Good explanation! - and the function does as intended on my data as well in reasonable time.